# how to access elements of an associative array in perl

Tags: perl, associative-array

i have the below code

```
my %ages = (); 

$a1 = "Michael Caine";
$a2 = "Dirty Den";
$a3 = "Angie";
$a4 = "Willy";
$a5 = "The Queen Mother";

$ages{$a1} = 39;
$ages{$a2} = 34;
$ages{$a3} = 27;
$ages{$a4} = "21 in dog years";
$ages{$a5} = 108;

print $age->{$a1};
```

but this is not printing . i do not want to use keys or values. how can i access the contents of hash using `'$age->{$a1}'` type syntax?

Comment: There is nothing called $age in there, just $ages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to access `$age` which does not exist.
Also, you are trying to use extra reference `->`, which is wrong.

You need to use this:

```
$ages{$a1}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you access to hash, you have to do it on this way:

```
print $ages{$a1};
```

Because it is not a reference.

I recommend you read the [book *Modern Perl*](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/), it has helped me so much.

Comment: when you program, don't forget use:
use warnings;
use strict;

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

```
  sub storeArray {
        $hash = {
            key1 => [1,2,3,4,5],
            key2 => [6,7,8,9,0],
        };
        return $hash;   # don't return reference cause it already is 
    }

print $hash->{'key1'}->[0][2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a hash dereference

```
$ages->{$a1}
```

You first need a hash reference

```
my $ages = \%ages;
```